# I also want to change the background color of the Navigation Bar while it is fixed. How can I do?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I'm developing a notes application and I want the colors of the notes to match the color of the Navigation Bar. When I set the color of the Navigation Bar, the color appears only when I scroll the screen. I want the color to show up without scrolling the screen.

## Screenshot without scrolling

[image]

## Screenshot with scrolling

[image]

I use a Xcode 14 and Swift 5
I tried `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.flatSkyBlue()` AND `navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatSkyBlue()` but it didn't work.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure your navBar like this, in viewDidLoad declare UINavigationBarAppearance and set navigation bar:

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // set your bg color
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true // false if you don't want large title
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.title = "title"
```